# SQL Server Data Tools - September 2013 update fails

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When installing Sql Server Data Tools for visual studio 2012 professional, I get the following error:

"A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file."

Does anyone know of a way to resolve this?

Comment: set your clock back and re try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set your clock back to before 10/6 and then run the SSDTSetup.exe installer

source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/51ef983f-1f07-41b4-bad4-3541e93d4647/known-issue-ssdt-install-fails-validating-certificates?forum=ssdt

Comment: I set the time back, and the install worked perfectly...Thanks!